# How to send error/success message through ajax without click submit button in form (if there isn't form) laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

How to send error/success message through ajax without click submit button in form (if there isn't form)?

I'm doing a laravel project in there I've used the method when user submit the form the form goes to controller (through form's action attribute) and inside the controller function it can return view with data and redirect the page so the error/success message will be shown and page will be refreshed.

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Successfully Added!');
```

But the case is I want to click a button and same thing happen if there are no form. I added onclick to button and run a js function to call controller via ajax. But after call to controller the above code doesn't work like before. No error either.

```
<button type="button"  onclick="submit()" class="btn btn-primary"
>Submit</button> 

<script>
//when click submit button
    function submit(){
        var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('RecipeController.submit') }}",
            type: "POST",               
            data: { _token:_token                                     
            }
        })   
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone give me a solution?

Below I added message code if you want that.

```
@if(count($errors)>0)
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">    
        {{$error}}
    </div>    
@endforeach
@endif

@if(session('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{session('success')}}        
</div>    
@endif

@if(session('error'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{session('error')}}        
</div>    
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax normally expects JSON, so a normal redirect or view wont work.

I can show you an example:

```
    return response()->json(['error' => 'there was an error...'], 200);
```

The 1st parameter is an array with the data. The second is the http status.

Hope it helps with your problem. :)

Edit: Now that i have your message code.

You just have to add a div dynamically with js on ajax success.

Comment: Nothing happened. Do I have to put something in ajax success{ }?

Comment: Well, you have to manually code the success yes. 
I usually have a little js shared in all views where i manage the ajax response.
In the response, i just send the kind of message (success, error, warning...), title and text.

Example:

        `return response()->json(['title' => 'Changes saved', 'text' => 'all went fine :)', 'type' => 'success'], 200);`

Comment: I just dont understand what you said "You just have to add a div dynamically with js on ajax success." Can you explain it please?

Comment: Yes, with javascript, you send an ajax request. When it finish, you have a response, this response contains the data you need for the message.

Then, i saw your messages are just <div> tags with a text inside. So you just need to write a little piece of code that when you get the ajax response create a div with the response data.

JQuery example: `$('body').append('<div class="alert alert-{RESPONSE_PARAMETER}" >RESPONSE MESSAGE</div>');`

Comment: ah I got it. Thanks

Comment: If you think mine was the correct answer u could gimme thumbs up and mark my answer as valid! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
               $(".removeproduct").click(function(){

                   $.ajax({
                       headers: {
                           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                       },
                       type : 'DELETE',
                       url  : '/user/'+report_id+'/removefromcart',
                       data  : {report_id : report_id},
                       success:function(data)
                       {
                           console.log(data);
                      },
                       error : function(data)
                       {
                           console.log(data);
                       }
                     });


                   });
               }) ;
```

And route should be defined like

```
Route::get('/user/{id}/removefromcart','YOURCONTROLLERNAME@MethodName');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function removeFromCart(Request $request, $report_id)
{

    $return = array();


        $check = DB::delete("DELETE FROM carts WHERE user_id='" . Auth::user()->user_id . "' AND report_id='" . $report_id . "'");
        if ($check) 
        {

            $count = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)->count('id');
            $return = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Item removed to cart', 'data' => $count);
            return response()->json($return);
        }

    } 


}
```